# Port forwarding in docker does not work

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, docker

I have installed docker on my ubuntu 16.04 and have run a machine on port 52022 and enable ssh for that machine on port 2242.

I have also opened 52022 on the firewall with this

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 52022 -j ACCEPT
```

now I can curl to VM inside the host with this

```
curl http://localhost:52022
```

and it shows me this `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2`

and I can log in to VM from the host with these

```
ssh root@localhost -p 52022

docker attach name
```

and when I run `lsof -i :52022`, it says that VM is listening on that port

but I can't ssh to my VM from outside of the host
`ssh@hostipaddress -p  52022` does not work
Could you please tell me why?
Thank you

Comment: Did you checked the SSH Server logs?

Comment: Did you EXPOSE the port?

Comment: Please show how you are running your docker container. Include output from the commands you are running, we cannot see your screen.